# Best way to populate this array using .txt file?

Tags: arrays, cocoa

I'm looking to make SEVERAL arrays populated with words. Eventually I want to be able to just pull a random word from the array and display it (I've mastered that). What I'm wondering is what is the best way to populate this array. Should I just type in:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"word1",@"word2",@"word3",@"word4",@"word5",nil]
```

or is there a better way where the words are stored in a .txt file and I can just have a loop add each word in the text file to the Array?

I'm looking at filling the arrays with 100's of words. Any and all help is appreciated  :D.

**UPDATE**

After doing some research I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011898/iphone-nsarray-how-do-i-format-a-text-file-to-be-read-in-using-arraywithconte). It seems to be exactly what I wanted. The only thing is it gives me a warning

> 'stringWithContentsOfFile' is deprecated

I know the full NSString method is:

```
stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *) encoding:(NSStringEncoding) error:(NSError **)
```

But I don't know what to put for encoding (and I'm assuming I can just put 'nil' for NSError). Other than that it works like a charm. I might consider switching from paths to urls. Here is the code that I found:

```
- (NSArray *) readFile:(NSString *) path {


NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *dict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSCharacterSet *cs = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:file];

NSString *line;
while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    if([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:cs intoString:&line]) {
        NSString *copy = [NSString stringWithString:line];
        [dict addObject:copy];

    }
}
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:dict];

return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` for the `encoding` parameter (depending on how you created the file, but this is the most common).

Instead of using `NSScanner`, you can also simply split the string into lines with the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method. This reduces your method to just these two lines:

```
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
return [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Btw, you shouldn't name an array variable "dict", this would imply that it's an `NS(Mutable)Dictionary`.

Comment: any major difference between setting the error to nil or NULL?

Comment: And thanks! This works like a freaking charm (Might change the path to an NSUR) But thanks!!!!!!

Comment: You can use `nil` or `NULL`, it's mostly a matter of style. I prefer to use `NULL` when it refers to a pointer and not an object reference. This makes it clearer that the parameter is of type `NSError**` and not `NSError*`.

Answer (score 0):

The less code way to get in a list of words would be:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Words" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *words = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Then you just have to create a plist that has all the words in it with the root object as an array.

In the method you have above the encoding you are looking for is `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and you actually should pass an NSError by reference, if something goes wrong the error could be useful:

```
NSError *anError = nil;
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&anError];
```

Comment: What's the most direct way to create a plist? (I don't have too  much experience with those.)

Comment: If you create a new file in Xcode one of the options is to create a plist (shown as Property List I think). In Xcode 3.x there was also a Property list editor app that you could use. With Xcode 4 you just need to make it so that the root object is an Array. To verify this just look at the file in plain text and make sure that the last two tags are `</array>` then `</plist>` if there is something in the middle of those remove it and it's counterpart at the beginning of the file.