# Change text of a label

Tags: objective-c, arrays, button, ios6, label

I have a array that reads a .txt file and when you click a button the label changes in one of the words of the .txt file, but the label doen't change.

This is the code:

```
if(sender == self.button) {
    NSArray *words = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"words.txt", nil];
    [randomLabel setText:[words objectAtIndex:random() % [words count]]];
}
```

What should I do so the label changes when I press the button?
What file do I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here:

### Reading in file into an array

Well, for starters you're not reading in the contents of the .txt file.

```
NSArray *words = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"words.txt", nil];
```

This creates a 1 element array, with that one element being `@"words.txt"`. I don't know the format of your .txt file, so I can't say for sure how you have to load it in. See [How do I format a text file to be read in using arrayWithContentsOfFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011898/how-do-i-format-a-text-file-to-be-read-in-using-arraywithcontentsoffile) on how to potentially do this.

### Setting button text

Also, you need to make sure `randomLabel` actually refers to the label contained within the button, otherwise the button text won't change. Typically for a button, you'd change the title using the method:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

So in your instance, it'd be:

```
NSString* newTitle = [words objectAtIndex:random() % [words count]];
[self.button setTitle:newTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

### Is the code actually being called?

Double check that `sender == self.button` evaluates to true (for readability and clarity, I'd use `[sender isEqual:self.button]`). Use the debugger to step through the code, to see if that particular piece of code is being called. See http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/xcode-debugging_iphone-sdk/ on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath